# Adding Firebase to your Flutter app with Flutter Icon

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-tools

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTnmD.jpg)

I want to connect my Flutter app with Firebase with new Flutter Icon in Firebase. But after doing the steps, and especially this step:

> Then, at the root of your Flutter project directory, run this command:

[image]

I got this error in my cmd

> i Found 0 Firebase projects. Selecting project chatapp1-5a9b5.
> FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I read the error message in the screenshot correctly it says that the Firebase CLI needs to be installed, so did you install that? If not yet, have a look at the documentation on [installing the Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#setup_update_cli).

Comment: Yes, I did. After I run this command ******              flutterfire configure --project=chatapp1-5a9b5 ****                this error pops up ***            FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase --version
ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it. ***

Comment: From that it sounds like the `firebase` CLI itself is not installed, or that the `flutterfire` CLI can't find it. If you open a *new* terminal window and run `firebase --version`, what do you get?

Comment: I got 10.9.2 for the command

Comment: I have done these process by another machine (windows 10) and received the same error.